# How to receive payments in PayPal account

Tags: ios, paypal

I have an app in which I have to receive payment within the app
The flow should be as below

1. user A will pay to merchant
2. Merchant will deduct his fee (say 10% )
3. merchant will send 80% to user b who do the service

My question is how we can transfer money from Merchant to user B

Can we ask a user to enter **PayPal** detail in a form and send that to our own server and then we can make the transfer?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to accomplish that.

1)  You could use the setup a [chained payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-basicChainedPayment-curl-etc/) with the [Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/adaptive-payments/) API and it would handle the split of the money between the different accounts for you.  You could even do a delayed chained payment if you need to delay the funds to the secondary receiver(s).

2) You could setup a regular PayPal checkout of any kind (Payments Standard, Express Checkout, etc.) with the merchant site, and then use the [Pay](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) API (which again would be part of Adaptive Payments) or the [MassPay](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/MassPay_API_Operation_NVP/) API to send payments out to the secondary receiver(s).